# Superimpose two plots with tikZ or pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

The net effect should be the following
[image]
Basically, it is a zoom, except I don’t want to actually magnify a portion of a graph, but putting another more detailed one instead.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14432/tikz-spy-library-with-pgfplots-opacity-and-grid can help? In general, looking for `pgfplots` and the `spy library` would give you several hits. Another one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116697/38080

Answer (score 1):

Note: If you need more inner nodes you could use two scopes.

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, dashed, ellipse, minimum width=40mm, minimum height=30mm, anchor=south west] (plot1) at (0,0) {plot 1};
    \node[draw, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=7mm, x={(plot1.south east)}, y={(plot1.north west)}] (hlbox) at (.9,.7) {};
    \node[draw, minimum width=30mm, minimum height=20mm, above right=of plot1, xshift=10mm] (plot2) {plot 2};
    \draw[->] (plot2.south west) -- (hlbox.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. One last thing: when I add ```\foreach \x in {1,...,300}{--++(0.03,{0.1*(floor(rand)*2.0+1.0)*sqrt(-ln(1-rand^2)/0.627)})}``` in place of ```{plot 1}``` pdflatex doesn't compile. Why?

Comment: You should ask a new question for unrelated stuff. `{plot 1}` is the text content of the node. You can't put tikz commands in there.